# Total value of warehouse active record

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have the object Tool and I need to calculate the cost of all the Tools in the warehouse.
I can sum the column price  `Tool.sum(:price)` but i need to sum (quantity * price) of all the table Tools.
Thanks in advance.

```
create_table "tools", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "quantity"
    t.string "name"
    t.integer "price"
    t.boolean "avilable"
    t.string "store"
    t.string "comments"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the example listed for [ActiveRecord::Calculations#calculate](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-calculate).

You can do the following:

```rb
  Tool.sum("quantity * price")
```

Comment: So simple, works perfect.
<%= number_to_currency(Tool.sum("quantity * price"), delimiter: ".", precision: 0) %>

Comment: Awesome stuff!!